# take-vector-screenshot: focusing the window before taking the screenshot

Tags: screenshot, wmctrl

I am using `take-vector-screenshot` to take a PDF screenshot.

When I launch `take-vector-screenshot`, I have to click a button within its window in order to begin the screenshot process. I then need to pick the window to take a screenshot of.

[image: A button is required to be clicked to start the process]

In the process of clicking this button (pictured above), the focus changes from the window which I actually want to capture. Hence the screenshot I get is of an unfocussed window, which is undesirable.

I can use `wmctrl -a $WINDOW_TITLE` to focus the window I want to take the screenshot of, but this doesn't work if I precede it with e.g. a `sleep 3`.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

This (somehow) appears to be related to my shell.

If I run `bash` and then try `sleep 2; wmctrl -a WindowTitle`, it works fine.

Fails every time in `zsh` though - no idea why.

**This doesn't solve the problem though**: because the window still gets unfocussed when the save dialog appears. I fixed this part of the issue by [forking](https://github.com/lol768/gtk-vector-screenshot) `gtk-vector-screenshot` and adding calls to `gtk_window_set_accept_focus(window, False);`. I also removed the save dialog, so PDFs just get written to the home directory. It's a hack, but the project isn't being maintained anymore and it does the job for me.